# problem logging in at meta stack overflow

Tags: support, login

Trying to login at
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/login

via StackExchange (leftmost item) gives the error message:

`Third Party Cookies Appear To Be Disabled
This site depends on third-party cookies, please add an exception for https://openid.stackexchange.com/.`

How to add such an exception? (I am working with Mozilla Firefox 11.0 for Ubuntu canonical - 1.0.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you open the "preferences" (Mac) or "options" (Windows) tool, and look on the "Privacy" tab.

Comment: It worked, thanks!